# Forecasting monthly stock returns with daily data and down-sampling concerns

Tags: forecasting, arima, garch, volatility-forecasting, down-sample

I have daily stock return data (log returns). I want to forecast returns for the next two months. I am creating forecasts with both univariate ARIMA and GARCH models with regressors.

What are the dangers /assumptions I am making if I downsample the daily data to the month level of aggregation? I am concerned with the following:

1. If I downsample to weekly data, is this better than monthly given my data is daily and the goal of forecast accuracy?
2. Financial data does not include weekends (market's close). Does this affect how I should think about downsampling?

If these questions are too many for this post, are there time series books that have a focusing on the implications of down and upsampling on forecasting results?

Comment: I think you are correct that this might be closed as having too many questions unless you edit it down.